# how to call onAction(ActionEvent event) method in javafx

Tags: java, events, javafx, event-handling, javafx-8

I am having a problem in javafx when calling onAction(ActionEvent event) method in initialize() method.

This is javafx code:

```
public class MainViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label lblHeading;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        btnLoginUserOnAction(null);
    }

    @FXML
    private void btnLoginUserOnAction(ActionEvent event) {
        String getId = ((Button) event.getSource()).getText();
        lblHeading.setText(getId);
    }

}
```

How i call `btnLoginUserOnAction(ActionEvent event)` in `initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)`. If i pass `null` to `ActionEvent` parameter then i shows `execption` because `Event` us `null`.

Any help???

Comment: why? It's called when the user clicks the button (provided your fxml setup is correct)

Comment: I also try `btnLoginUserOnAction(new ActionEvent());`. But not works???

Comment: Because, I have many button in `nav-bar`. and i want the first button i pressed when scene load. so that codding repetition is minimum..

Comment: again: what do you want to achieve by calling the method from initialize? Anyway, please read a basic tutorial to understand how buttons are supposed to be used ... the info tab of the javafx tag has references. And then provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are after and how it doesn't fit your requirements

Comment: I wants that, I have to  only set `onAction` in scene builder. And then i get text from that button through its `ActionEvent` and then set it to another label. I want to virtualy press button in `initialize` method. any confusion???

Comment: Are your buttons are predefined, or dynamically loaded?

Comment: Why not assign the same text to `Button`&`Label` in the fxml? BTW: to create a `ActionEvent` instance that would work with the handler method would require access to the button in question. Since you only inject a `Label`, you'd have to navigate to the button through the scene structure via the label's ancestors, which is a terrible idea